# Japanese Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, localization

I'm trying to provide a Japanese installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 to a user for localization testing. I've done this before with Windows XP which seemed to have a Japanese specific disc. I can't find a similar method for installing a Japanese version of Windows Server 2008 R2.

**My Question:**
Is there a difference between a localized version of Windows Server 2008 R2 and an English version with the Japanese language pack installed?

This [question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winservergen/thread/b8a9e773-2149-4800-bce4-a722c9455f6d) on the technet forums is similar to mine but the answer is not clear to me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Additional display languages on Windows Server 2008 R2: Error while installing](https://serverfault.com/questions/336590/additional-display-languages-on-windows-server-2008-r2-error-while-installing) for more info - I think the distinction in the first answer between language packs and localization via license is what you're looking for.

Comment: This leads me to believe there is one international version of the operating system that supports overlaying language packs. As far as I can tell an English installation configured with a "fully localized pack" is indistinguishable from a copy purchased off the shelf in Japan. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some difference because similarly I installed OS windows server 2008 R2 with Japanese pack but still application displays some junk values .so I guess installing OS in Japanese language is option.